Project with Odoo and Power BI
I'm working on a project to create Power BI dashboards using Odoo as a data source. I'm using the Activity-Based Costing (ABC) method to identify hidden costs and reduce overall costs for a business. However, I'm facing challenges in identifying costs because I lack knowledge about how different departments in an enterprise, such as purchasing management and sales management, etc. This lack of understanding is hindering my progress in defining key performance indicators (KPIs) for my project. Additionally, I'm struggling to find Odoo's database schema and determine the most important tables for my project. Furthermore, I'm unsure how to create models for my KPIs.
I tried researching enterprises and activities that generate costs to create my KPIs, but it was not successful. It would be really helpful if someone could assist me with identifying my KPIs, creating models for them, and determining what modules to use in Odoo for my project.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Let's begin by installing Odoo using the all-in-one Yenthee script, that will install the odoo database schema. Then, you could use a database graph tool, for instance: DbVisualizer (dbvis.com), that enables to select the database-tables that you want to display:

First, you should get basic knowedge about the odoo architecture and models : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/17.0/developer/tutorials/server_framework_101/01_architecture.html
Before creating your own model, yo should inspect the existing nativ models in /odoo/src/addons directory to get familiar with (basic guide: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/17.0/developer/tutorials/server_framework_101/02_newapp.html).
in Odoo, each activity department (ex: Sale, Accounting) correspond mostly to a so called "Odoo-Application", that consists in several models (sale.order, sale.order.line, account.move ...). A record of the sale-order Model (ex: a sale.order) relates to the record of the invoice Model (account.move) by using binding fields (types: one2many, many2one or many2many), that bind the key(id) of one model-record to the key(s) of (an)other model-record(s). More info here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/17.0/developer/tutorials/server_framework_101/03_basicmodel.html
Here an example of the relations between database-tables that store the employee data (job, skills, categories...):

image2 source: https://2021.desosa.nl/print/projects/odoo/posts/essay_2/
